# reference of extension of flat bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry

Does any one know where one can find a reference about the following fact?

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over an algebraically closed field $k$. 
Fix two flat bundles $(L_i,\nabla_i)$ over $X$, (vector bundles with integrable connections) for $i=1,2$. 
Define a new flat bundle $(M,\nabla_M)$ with $M= L_2^*\otimes L_1$ and $\nabla_M=\nabla_2^*\otimes \nabla_1$.

Then all extension classes 
$$
0\to (L_1,\nabla_1)\to (H,\nabla)\to (L_2, \nabla_2)\to 0
$$ 
are described by the  first deRham cohomology of $(M,\nabla_M)$ (hypercohomology of the deRham complex).

Comment: By the usual tensoring stuff, one can reducing to the case when $(L_2, \nabla_2) = (O_X, {\rm{d}})$ (i.e., the unit object) and $(L_1, \nabla_1) = (M, \nabla_M)$.  The relevant calculation is then given early in the book of Mazur and Messing ("Universal extensions and one-dimensional crystalline cohomology").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking at extensions of $L_2$ by $L_1$ as $\mathcal{D}_X$-modules, which  are classified by $\mathrm{Ext}^1_{\mathcal{D}_X}(L_2,L_1)\cong \mathrm{Ext}^1_{\mathcal{D}_X}(\mathcal{O}_X,M)$. Now it is  well-known  in the theory of $\mathcal{D}$-modules that there is a canonical isomorphism of $R\mathcal{H}om_{\mathcal{D}_X}(\mathcal{O}_X,M)$ with the de Rham complex $\Omega ^._X\otimes M$, so $\mathrm{Ext}^1_{\mathcal{D}_X}(\mathcal{O}_X,M)$ is canonically isomorphic to $H^1_{dR}(M)$.